How to Decode data from get_account_info in Solana Using Python?
I’m working with the Solana blockchain in Python and trying to decode the binary data returned from an account request (Raydium pool). When I request account information with:
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
import json
import base64
solana_client = Client("https://thrilling-withered-sheet.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/a0d9c563e6ed34fa17d4b012518a593834fbc86e/")

resp_ = solana_client.get_account_info(Pubkey.from_string('EwxCuTua1op5drWWwYbAwnyWHgC5N5vo3HoESipVNTXA'), encoding='base64')
print(resp_)
resp = json.loads(resp_.to_json())
data_b64 = resp['result']['value']['data'][0]
data = base64.b64decode(data_b64)
print(data)

The data field contains a long binary sequence, which looks something like this:
b"\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07 ........\x00\x00\x00"

I need to decode this binary sequence to extract needed information such as balances, token contracts, and other pool-specific data.  Could anyone please guide me on:

How to identify the structure of data for Raydium pools and others types of accounts
Any Python libraries or methods (e.g., struct module) that might help in decoding Solana account data
As a variant, maybe some public API exists I can retrieve needed info from, but I wasn't able to find it ...

Thank you for any pointers or examples!

You'll need some form of schema (typically called an IDL) to know how to deserialize account bytes. Otherwise, on-chain programs will typically publish an SDK to use their program and understand their data structures. Here's that library for Raydium (but it's JS) https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk
